# Period being identified as ASCII code 190?

Tags: javascript

Developing a web app using javascript in a .cshtml webpage, I'm using a function that checks user input to make sure its a number or period/decimal point before being entered into a textbox.

The original code(found here! :) :

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode != 46 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I added alert(charCode); before the if, and what popped up was 190. ASCII 190 is the YEN symbol.

I edited the code to accept ASCII 190 and my period/decimal point is now showing up.

I'm new to programming/web development. Why did I encounter the issue I did? Is there a fix?

-TC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the difference between characters for visualization and key codes.

Most of the key codes are mapped to a char values you know from the ASCII table.

But the dot for example has multiple positions on a keyboard.
The dot on the numpad has a different value than the dot in the text space.

This was very helpful for me to understand this in the past https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode.

Comment: also worth mentioning the deprecation warnings on the page you link to

Comment: @Patrick Thank you.
This is not good news though. I just tried using the numpad to do entries. I wasn't surprised when it didn't work =/ 

Off to code a new solution...

Answer (score 0):

Once I learned that keycode and ASCII are not the same I found out: Keycode is the keyboard location, ASCII is the byte table representation. But its even deeper than that. onkeydown="isNumberKey()" returns the keycode, onKeyPress="isNumberKey()" returns the ASCII,.. at least in Chrome and IE and Edge included with win10.